# unable to convert Nsarray's object into string

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsarray

i am trying to convert array object into string but still it is returning address of object.
it is returning - **0x5e1e370**
but should return some string value .

```
NSMutableArray *arrStudents = [pillboxDb getStudentRecords];
NSString *strHow = [arrStudents objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",strHow);
```

Here is the code for getStudentRecords

```
+(NSMutableArray*)getStudentRecords{

NSArray *arrDocPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *strDestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/samplepillbox1.sqlite",[arrDocPath objectAtIndex:0]];
NSMutableArray *arrStudents = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sqlite3 *db;
if(sqlite3_open([strDestPath UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *query = @"select * from doctor_master";
    void* v;
    char* err_msg;
    sqlite3_stmt *studentStmt;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &studentStmt, &err_msg)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(studentStmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            int sno = sqlite3_column_int(studentStmt, 0);
            NSString *sname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: sqlite3_column_text(studentStmt, 1)];
            //float marks = sqlite3_column_double(studentStmt, 2);

            pillbox *st = [[pillbox alloc]init];
            st.Din = sno;
            st.Name = sname;

            [arrStudents addObject:st];
        }

    }

}
return arrStudents;
```

}

Comment: is it CoreData objects ?

Comment: Are you sure that your array is filled with `NSString` objects? Please  do this to verify: `NSLog(@"%@", [[arrStudents objectAtIndex:0] class]);`

Comment: how you are filling "pillboxDb" array ? show the code

Comment: Before nsstring you just check your arrstudents have any object or not?using nslog in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrStudents = [pillboxDb getStudentRecords];
pillbox *st = [arrStudents objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@ , %d", st.Name,st.Din);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *strHow = [[arrStudents objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

it is perhaps your return object is not a string object. try

NSLog(@"%@",arrStudents);

it will show you object type and then concate the strings using that object

Comment: it is showing like this.. "<pillbox: 0x68353d0>",
    "<pillbox: 0x6835460>",
    "<pillbox: 0x6835490>",
    "<pillbox: 0x68354c0>",
    "<pillbox: 0x6835a50>"

Comment: do you have any class name pillBox?

Comment: ya that's the point. array will return objects as you added to it. you added pillbox objects and trying to get it as string which will not be allowd. use

pillBox* objStd = [arrStudents objecAtIndex:i];

Comment: it will return a pillbox object and use pillbox attributes to retrive data. or add string objects to array when you add objects to array

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = [arrStudents ObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom pillBox class (btw, coding convention is that it should be names PillBox) is using the standard NSObject description method:

> description Returns a string that represents the contents of the
>   receiving class.

```
+ (NSString *)description
```

> Return Value A string that represents the contents of the receiving
>   class.
>
> Discussion The debugger’s print-object command invokes this method to
>   produce a textual description of an object.
>
> NSObject's implementation of this method simply prints the name of the
>   class.

Override description to provide the value you want. Or, create a stringValue method that provides the string you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding objects of pillbox class into the array.So u have to first access the pillbox object like

```
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
pillbox *pill=[array objectAtIndex:i];

NSLog(@"%@  %@",pillbox.Name,pillbox.Din);
}
```

now from that pillbox u have to access the pillbox.Name and pillbox.Din as strings u cant directly convert an array to string!